# Edit a cs file and the project wont build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have downloaded a C# project viewing it in VS 2013. All works fine and I can step through the code...However When I try to add extra code to the program_org file it doesnt run I get the error saying FILE NOT FOUND (Please see image) [image]

I Have found alot of similar Qs online but none have resolved my issue, I have tried tools->Options->Debugging->General->Enable source server support

Does anyone have any advice?

thank you

Comment: Open .csproj file and check the path of the file 'Program_Org.cs' in that. This should be a relative path. Ensure that the path of the file defined in '.csproj' file and the actual location of the file is the same.

Comment: check csproj file to see if 'Program_Org.cs is there. it can be excluded from the project. including it from solution will resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply..so just to test I edited the path to be the exact location on my local computer and I am still getting this error.