# Why cant I find my .csproj file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, csproj

VS 2013. Following on from my previous Q of not being able to edit a file without causing a crash [Edit a cs file and the project wont build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639822/edit-a-cs-file-and-the-project-wont-build) seems to be a csproj issue.

I have followed the instructions I found:

```
  To edit a .csproj (or any other project file) directly from Visual Studio, do the following:

    Right click the project in Solution Explorer
    Select "Unload project"
    Project is now unloaded
    Right click the project again and select "Edit blah.csproj"
    Make your changes and save them
    Right click the project and select "Reload project" to apply the changes
```

However unload project is not available (please see image)

why is this?[image]

I Have done a complete search of the folder and .csproj does not exist? How is this possible

Comment: Not sure why you can't see the unload project from the context menu. Can you view the csproj file with the XML editor?

Comment: You can try going to settings, Projects and Solutions/General and check “Always show solution” checkbox, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Potential answer, at least for VS2022
Here's the Solution Explorer view of my current project (super-retro RogueLike console game in C#)
[image: Solution Explorer view]

If I click on the top level of the solution explorer ("Solution 'RogueLike Tutorial' (1 of 1 project)"), I get the menu like you showed, with no Unload Project option:
[image: No Unload Project option!]

But if I go one item lower in the menu, to "RogueLikeTutorial" (with the C# badge), I get the following menu, which is the one you were looking for:
[image: Unloadable project achievement unlocked!]

No idea if that was the case almost 5 years ago in VS 2013, but finding your question and the comments helped me when I just ran into this issue in VS 2022. I hope this helps any future time travelers!